# Android Application : How do I get touch event on Home Screen when the app in Background Action

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-touch-event

Using WindowManager, I make the app  floaintView in home screen  like Facebook Messenger.

MotionEvent allows to move the Floated View.
I'd like to set up WindowManager Flag and get a touch event for a screen other than Floating, but it's not working...

When I touch the floating view, It works well. By calling OnTouchListener, ACTION_DOWN ACTION_UP,

When I touch outside the Window( Home Screen), I Want it works well  both Doing other Job(Touching other App) and  Calling  Listener
Please anyone guide me how I can get touch event in my app so I can do some task.
*I used three all flags*
FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE

1. FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
   On the Home screen, it touchs of the rest of the window, but fails to invoke the touch of the OnClickListener.
2. FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
   Touch other than Floating View is blocked.

   @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
   override fun onCreate() {
   super.onCreate()
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) startMyOwnForeground() else startForeground(
   1,
   Notification()
   )

   ```
    //Inflate the floating view layout we created
    mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.test, null)

    val LAYOUT_FLAG: Int
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE

    }

    params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LAYOUT_FLAG,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )

    //Specify the view position
    params!!.gravity =
        Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
    params!!.x = 0
    params!!.y = 100

    //Add the view to the window
    mWindowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    mWindowManager!!.addView(mFloatingView, params)

    var test = mFloatingView!!.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.wrap_container)
    with(test) {
        setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            private var initialX = 0
            private var initialY = 0
            private var initialTouchX = 0f
            private var initialTouchY = 0f
            override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                Log.d("aa", "aa")
                when (event.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        Log.d("ACTION_DOWN", "ACTION_DOWN")
                        //remember the initial position.
                        initialX = params!!.x
                        initialY = params!!.y

                        //get the touch location
                        initialTouchX = event.rawX
                        initialTouchY = event.rawY

                        return true
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        Log.d("ACTION_UP", "ACTION_UP")

                        val Xdiff = (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                        val Ydiff = (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()


                        //The check for Xdiff <10 && YDiff< 10 because sometime elements moves a little while clicking.
                        //So that is click event.
                        if (Xdiff < 10 && Ydiff < 10) {
                            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            intent.putExtra("fromwhere", "ser")
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        return true
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {

                        Log.d("ACTION_MOVE", "ACTION_MOVE")
                        //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                        params!!.x = initialX + (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                        params!!.y = initialY + (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()


                        //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                        mWindowManager!!.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params)
                        return true
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE -> {

                        Log.d("ACTION_OUTSIDE", "ACTION_OUTSIDE")
                        //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                        initialX = params!!.x
                        initialY = params!!.y

                        //get the touch location
                        initialTouchX = event.rawX
                        initialTouchY = event.rawY

                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        })
    }
   ```

   }

'''